# Netezza datepart function not working as expected

Tags: sql, netezza

I am trying to get the number of days between 2 dates in Netezza, but is not working. I am putting the dates as 31AUG2015 and 01SEP2015, and expecting an answer of 1. 
But when I do this:

```
select
extract (day from to_date('31082015','DDMMYYYY') - (to_date('01092015','DDMMYYYY')))
```

I get 31.

By reversing the dates, I can get 1:

```
select
extract (day from to_date('01092015','DDMMYYYY') - (to_date('31082015','DDMMYYYY')))
```

But why does the first query return 31?

Answer (score 0):

I just need to subtract one date from another to get the number of days in between

select to_date('31082015','DDMMYYYY') - to_date('01092015','DDMMYYYY')